# How to set only path name using Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am confused about to set path using Angular.js. Suppose I have initially the url is `http://localhost/crm/deal.php#/catagory`.

In this URL I only need to change `deal.php#/catagory` to `dashboard.php`. I am using `ui-router` for routing the state.

Comment: Can you add the $stateProvider code you are using st the moment?

Comment: `$interval(function(){
    $window.location.href = "http://localhost/crm/dashboard.php";
   },5000)` here i am adding the total url which is not right.I need to set only path .

Comment: You can use relative urls like "/crm/dashboard.php", but this isn't related to ui-router. Do you just want to redirect the user to the dashblard.php, then location.href will do it. However if you want the user to see the content of  dashboard without(!) reloading the whole page you need to use ui router's stateProvider

Comment: Ok,Can you write your answer using `stateProvider`.any one example.

Comment: Sure but I'm on my way to work now,  I can answer this in  2 hours. You might setup a ui-router state using threir example code in the meantime. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that need to be taken care of one is client-side routing and the second is server-side routing.

If the HTML page is not tightly coupled with the server-side(PHP) then you are good to go with angular ui-router which will load the page only on the client. Here, by looking at the URLs/routs deal.php and dashboard.php it seems they need to render on the server. If this statement is correct then ui-router is not best suitable here.

But still, if you have something working using ui-router and need more help on that, the following link may help: [Redirect to login when user is not logged in or user tries to access page directly from URL using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860893/redirect-to-login-when-user-is-not-logged-in-or-user-tries-to-access-page-direct)