# Redirect to login when user is not logged in or user tries to access page directly from URL using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, redirect

I am creating a small project in which if user role is **Sales** then after login it will redirect user to sales form page.
Now how can I redirect user to Login page if user tries to access `Sales form` page by entering its path in URL and also user is not logged in.This is my Angular part.

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope,$http,$window){

    $scope.login = function(){            
           data={
                email:$scope.email,
                pwd:$scope.pwd
            }
            $http.post("widget/login.php",data).success(function(data){
                 console.log(data);
            if(!data.success){                     
                    $scope.errorMsg="username or password is incorrect"; 
            }
            else{                                                
                $scope.role=data.role;
                $scope.id=data.id;
                if(data.role == "admin"){
                    $window.location.href="AdminPage.html";
                }
                else if(data.role == "Sales"){
                    $window.location.href="sales_form.html";
                }
                else if(data.role == "Account"){
                    $window.location.href="account_form.html";
                }
                else if(data.role == "Technical"){
                    $window.location.href="Technical_Form.html";
                } 
                else{
                    $scope.errorMsg="username or password is incorrect";
                }   
            }

        });
    }

});
```

From this how can I redirect user to login page if user is not logged in or tries to access page directly from URL.
And One more thing I'm using PHP as Backend as you can see it in `$http.post` part so give your answer accordingly.Appreciate help and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Or  u can try this plugin [angular-permission](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-permission)

Comment: It looks like you're just getting started on this. How you are handling state/routing is really not the proper approach with angular. Before you get too far, I'd recommend checking out UI-Router for AngularJS here: https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use angular.js,angular-route.js, angular-cookies.js and app.js on
   index page as follows:

   ```
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
   ```
2. In app.js

   ```
       var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
      app.config(config);
      app.run(run);

   config.$inject = ['$httpProvider','$routeProvider', 
   '$locationProvider'];
   function config($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {       
    //Set routing
   $routeProvider
       .when('/login', {
           controller: 'LoginController',
           templateUrl: 'login/login.view.html',
           controllerAs: 'vm'
       })
         .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
      }

      //Write following code to make user login after page refresh
           run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore'];
     function run($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http, chatService) 
     {
      // keep user logged in after page refresh
     $rootScope.globals = $cookieStore.get('globals') || {};
   if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {           
      // set token in request header
     // $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 
        $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata; 

   }

     //On location change redirect user to login page if not login else 
    redirect based on role
     $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) 
    {
       // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a 
    restricted page
      //allow login and register page for all(login/notlogin) user
       var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', 
    '/register']) === -1;
       var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
       if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
           $location.path('/login');
       }
       else{
       $scope.role=$rootScope.globals.currentUser.user.role;               
           if(data.role == "admin"){
               $window.location.href="AdminPage.html";
           }
           else if(data.role == "Sales"){
               $window.location.href="sales_form.html";
           }
           else if(data.role == "Account"){
               $window.location.href="account_form.html";
           }
           else if(data.role == "Technical"){
               $window.location.href="Technical_Form.html";
           } 
           else{
               $scope.errorMsg="username or password is incorrect";
           }   
      }
   });
   }
   ```

   3. In login-Control write following code

      ```
        app.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope,$http,$window){
        $scope.login = function(){            
        data={
          email:$scope.email,
          pwd:$scope.pwd
         }
         $http.post("widget/login.php",data).success(function(data){                
      if(!data.success){                     
              $scope.errorMsg="username or password is incorrect"; 
      }
      else{ 
         //Set cookie
          $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
               user: data                   
          }                    

      $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
       //Redirect url
       $window.location.href="/";            
      }
      });
      ```

Comment: Finally got the answer I'm looking for.It is working for me and plus helping point is keep user logged in after page refresh part.

Answer (score 7):

you should use angular routing instead of $window.location.href.

Let me show you using ui-router.Add this line in index.html after angular library loaded.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

In your app.js

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller : 'LoginController'

        })

        // SALES PAGE AND MULTIPLE NAMED VIEWS =================================
        .state('sales', {
            url: '/sales',
            templateUrl: 'sales_form.html',
            controller : 'SalesController'
            ......
            ......

        });
     });
```

Now In your controller

```
   app.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope,$http,$window,$state){

    $scope.login = function(){            
           data={
                email:$scope.email,
                pwd:$scope.pwd
            }
            $http.post("widget/login.php",data).success(function(data){
                 console.log(data);
            if(!data.success){                     
                    $scope.errorMsg="username or password is incorrect";  
                    $state.go('login');            

            }
            else{                                                
                $scope.role=data.role;
                $scope.id=data.id;
                if(data.role == "admin"){
                    $state.go('admin'); //add admin state as admin in ui-router like sales
                }
                else if(data.role == "Sales"){
                    $state.go('sales');
                }
               .....

                else{
                    $scope.errorMsg="username or password is incorrect";
                    $state.go('login'); 
                }   
            }

        });
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the role variable in the rootscope so every controller can access it.

After login success, store the role variable in rootScope

```
            $rootScope.role=data.role;
```

Then in each controller check the value of the role and redirect the iser id the role is not matching the required role

```
            if($rootScope.role != "Sales"){
                $window.location.href="login.html";
            }
```

Comment: can you explain more about controller part I couldn't understand.Do I need to add `app.run` for this **If** condition.

Comment: It is redirecting to login page even I'm logged in.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a service to handle login/logout that also persists the loggedInState. Services are the proper scalable way to pass data around an angular app

```
module.service('LoginService', LoginService);

function LoginService() {
  var isLoggedIn = false;

  var service = {
    login: function() {
        //do login work
      loggedIn = true;
    },
    logout: function() {
        //do logout work
      loggedOut = false;
    },
    get isLoggedIn() {
      return isLoggedIn;
    }
  };

  return service;
}
```

You can use route resolve on the sales path to hit the `LoginService` and redirect to login if not logged in. More info here: https://johnpapa.net/route-resolve-and-controller-activate-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that Angular is running on the client and knowing PHP is running on the server, then I would not recommend doing this task in Angular, unless you have a good reason. This isn't because it can't be done, but because (typically) results from code run on a client machine should not be trusted, while results from code run on the server (typically) can be trusted.

In PHP

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION(['loggedIn']))
{
    if($_SESSION(['role']) == 'sales')
    {
        //Do something
    }

    //Do something else

}
else
{
    //Ask them to log in
}
```

By doing things in PHP (Or more accurately, by using a server side language) you can more closely fine tune what you want to have happen. What if someone disables Javascript? Will they have access to privileged information? What if someone is malicious (Needs not be an employee), can they hand craft a state on the client machine to gain access?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and resolved it through reffering some docs.

We had backend as Java,with angular js.I am posting the same which is working fine.It might help you.

**LogonController.js**

```
scope.loginMerchant  = function(merchant){
        MerchantRepository.loginMerchant(merchant)
        .then(function (response){

            scope.emailId=response.data.emailId;
            MerchantRepository.setEmailId(scope.emailId);
            if(response.data.userType == "merchant"){   
                state.go("merchanthome");
            }
            else
            {
                alert(" ID/Password is Invalid...");
                state.go("merchantlogon");
            }
        });
    };
```

**MerchantRepository.js**

You can do this way in your repository,So that during login it will set emailId.And retrieves whenever the url is accessed

```
this.setEmailId=function(emailId){
    this.emailId=emailId;
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("emailId",emailId);
}

this.getEmailId=function(){
    return window.sessionStorage.getItem("emailId");
}
```

**HomePageController.js**

```
scope.user=MerchantRepository.getEmailId();
if(scope.user== 'null' || scope.user== null){
    state.go("logon");
};
```

So each time you enter url of the page,The controller loads and checks for login details.If not present redirects to login Page.

**Edit**

And if you want to disable back button problem also.Adding this to above code will work.

**LogonController.js**

```
doMerchantLogout();

function doMerchantLogout() {
    MerchantRepository.doMerchantLogout().then(
             function(result) {
               scope.merchantSatus = result.data;
               scope.emailId= null;//so it set to null,this satisfies condition and redirects to login page
               MerchantRepository.setEmailId(scope.emailId);
               });
};
```

Hope it might help you.This is working snippet.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve your goal in my opinion is to create an input of type hidden, and pass the value  of your session: 1 if logged in and 0 if logged out as a sample.

Then create a condition inside Angular. If model value is = 0 then redirect to login page, else redirect somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

please try to use $state.

```
   angular.module('app',[])
   app.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope,$state){

    $scope.login = function(){            
           data={
                email:$scope.email,
                pswd:$scope.pswd
            }
            $http.post("/login.php",data).success(function(data){
                 console.log(data);
            if(!data.success){                     
                    $scope.errorMsg="username or password is incorrect";  
                    $state.go('app.login');            

            }
            else{                                                
                $scope.role=data.role;
                $scope.id=data.id;
                if(data.role == "admin"){
                    $state.go('app.admin'); //add admin state as admin in ui-router like sales
                }
                else if(data.role == "Sales"){
                    $state.go('app.sales');
                }
               ...
               ...

                else{
                    $scope.errorMsg="username or password is incorrect";
                    $state.go('app.login'); 
                }   
            }

        });
      }
   });
```