# AngularJS Authentication / Authorization via oAuth2 functionality

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, authorization

Can someone help to find a solve how to write this functionality on AngularJS?
Have java rest API and authorization server on one port and ui on other.
 Back-end authorization made by `oAuth2`. Need to make UI authorization.
 can someone help, please?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: If you need to authorize user only on UI then the following link will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860893/redirect-to-login-when-user-is-not-logged-in-or-user-tries-to-access-page-direct/44040191#44040191

Comment: If this is not what you want, please explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

if you are using AngularJs 1, you can use Satellizer. It's an AngularJs library to easily implement a token-based authentication.

Here is the GitHub link -> https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/

It is compatible with OAuth1, OAuth2 and has built-in support for the most popular provider (Google, Facebook, GitHub etc). I am using it for a current project and it perfectly works.

Please provide some details if you need any further help :)

Comment: Thanks! Will try it. And if I'll have some problems - will write here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oauth2 server you can authorize you rest enpoint via oauth token.

Make an http call at the loging form the frontend to necessary rest enpoint and take the relevant token and store it in the local storage.

Then use and http intercepter to attach the authorization header to each and every request.

If you need any codes or example drop me a message.